# java.time.Duration.dividedBy(long) vs java.time.Duration.dividedBy(Duration)

Tags: java, java-time

I am trying to divide two time durations (`java.time.Duration`) and to perform that there are two methods

1. `java.time.Duration#dividedBy(long)` which returns an object of type `Duration` itself but due to some API restrictions I can not use this version.
2. `java.time.Duraiton#dividedBy(Duration)` which returns a `long` and returns number of times one duration occurs within other duration but here we lose the precision as it does not care about the remainder.

Is there any way out to perform this division and get the result with remainder.

```java
Duration.ofHours(1).dividedBy(7L);  //returns 8M34.28571 seconds 
Duration.ofHours(1).dividedBy(Duration.ofSeconds(7L))  // returns 514 seconds
```

I have a restriction not to use the first way. Can I get the results using some other way?

**EDIT:** (from comments) I am not allowed to convert a Duration instance to an ordinal value, e.g. milliseconds.

Comment: What is `java.time.Duration(Duration)`?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#dividedBy-java.time.Duration-

Comment: I understand what `dividedBy(Duration)` is, but not what `java.time.Duration(Duration)` is. The latter makes it look like you're talking about a copy constructor but `Duration` has no public constructors.

Comment: Ahh apologies, I am talking about Duration.dividedBy(long) vs Duration.dividedBy(Duration)

Comment: I edited your question to try and make it clearer what I believe you're asking. You can rollback the edit if you don't like it, or obviously make whatever changes you want. But one thing: You said, "_due to some API restrictions I **can** use this version_", but did you mean to say "_due to some API restrictions I **cannot** use this version_"?

Comment: *due to some API restrictions* What restrictions do you have that allow you to use `Duration` but not certain methods on it?

Comment: What is your API restriction? If you have a `Duration` instance, nobody prevents you from converting it to an ordinal value, i.e. the number of elapsed milliseconds. You can then divide the other `Duration` with this value. If you cannot work with the resulting `Duration` object, then convert the result to ordinal.

Comment: You could try to use `BigInteger` to hack your way around.

Comment: But I think you need to provide more details about *what* exactly the tool blocks – is it *any* date and time related method which accepts a primitive integer type? Is it a blacklist of methods? In such case, you could be able to make a utility method to circumvent the limitation. *How* exactly is determined what method usages to block?

Answer (score 5):

Convert to milliseconds/nanoseconds, then divide their ordinal value(s), then create a new `Duration` object from the result.

Comment: Actually thats the restriction , can not convert Duration to primitive data type.

Comment: @Ankit It would be very helpful to mention this in the question. Why this restriction? The `java.time.Duration` class has methods to convert to/from ordinal values; why can't you use it?

Comment: For large durations this won’t work as it may be the case that you cannot fit all the nanos into a `long`. (Anything over about 292 years)

Comment: @knittl The reason is that often while converting dates to primitives developers make mistakes, so we have a binary in place which checks if the code is doing that and starts giving warnings for that piece of code. Otherwise would have easily used Duration.dividedBy(long)

Comment: Then it's time to get rid of this stupid checks which is preventing you from using the proper solution to problems. Implementation mistakes must make your unit tests fail (you have those, right?). More complicated solutions/workarounds are even more likely to be done incorrectly. Why not provide a simple `DurationUtil.convertToMillis(Duration)` helper? If this is implemented correctly (and unit tested!), everybody can use it. You might be able to disable your (sorry, stupid) check just for this one method.

Comment: Or perhaps the helper could provide `DurationUtil.divide(Duration, Duration)`, depending in your actual client code

Comment: *can not convert Duration to primitive data type.* Your `Duration.ofHours(1).dividedBy(7L)` is the clear, simple and recommended way and does not convert to any primitive type. What’s the trouble with it??

Answer (score 1):

When the easy ways are forbidden, you can of course do it the more cumbersome way. The following is similar to how we learned to do division by hand in school.

```
    Duration dividend = Duration.ofHours(1);
    long divisor = 7;
    
    long minutes = dividend.toMinutes() / divisor;
    dividend = dividend.minusMinutes(minutes * divisor);
    long seconds = dividend.toSeconds() / divisor;
    dividend = dividend.minusSeconds(seconds * divisor);
    long nanoseconds = dividend.toNanos() / divisor;
    
    Duration result = Duration.ofMinutes(minutes)
            .plusSeconds(seconds)
            .plusNanos(nanoseconds);
    
    System.out.println(result);
```

Result output:

> PT8M34.285714285S

Your requirements are not that precise, so I can’t be sure I haven’t used a forbidden method, though.

Comment: Which is definitely the "simpler" approach, given the OPs comment of »The reason is that often while converting dates to primitives developers make mistakes«. I bet nobody will make mistakes when converting the dates like that. At least the static code check is happy :D